# Why is object/associative array values not setting when I use $item.data("something").x

Tags: javascript, jquery

Why is it when I do something like

http://jsfiddle.net/sUhn9/

*Added relevant HTML*

```
<div id="container" data-physics='{x: 10, y: 5}'>Hello</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
$(function() {
    var obj = $("#container").data("physics");
    console.log("b4", obj);
    obj.x = -2;
    obj.y = -6;
    console.log("after", obj);
});
```

I get

```
b4 {x: 10, y: 5}
after {x: 10, y: 5}
```

Where x and y are not being set

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Working [update here](http://jsfiddle.net/sUhn9/2/) !!!

Well, for `data-physics='{x: 10, y: 5}'` `var obj = $("#container").data("physics");` returns string so `obj` is not an object so no property and ...

So to get it right, make it `data-physics='{"x": 10, "y": 5}'`, and everything should work fine.

Comment: just for understanding sake, is something like var `obj = {x: 10, y: 5}` not an object?

Comment: @jiewmeng `obj = {x: 10, y: 5}` is definitely an object but `.data("physics");` is returning `obj = '{x: 10, y: 5}'` which is not an object.

Comment: but how does putting x & y in quotes make '{"x": 10, "y": 5}' an object?

Comment: @jiewmeng Well, I don't have a clear but just a hypothesis. try the same thing using `parseJSON` function for two data, and `'{"x": 10, "y": 5}'` will fit in too, while `'{x: 10, y: 5}'` will generate and error, so I think `.data("physics")` depends on function or something like `parseJSON` which demands on that format.

Answer (score 2):

Your obj is not an object, it's a string. Changing the x and y properties for the string will not change the string itself.

You should do something like this:

```
var obj = jQuery.parseJSON($("#container").data("physics"));
```

Comment: As an alternate solution instead of parsing the string, the obj should just be placed in `.data()` without quotes (if possible), and it will be an object from the start. Although if that's not possible, then your solution is nice